# Errors with Web Server OAuth Implementation

Tags: connected-apps, oauth

I am trying to implement Web Server OAuth flow from one Salesforce Org to another.

Following is the Class which contains the logic. I am hitting custom rest api to insert Accounts using the access token.

```
public class WebServerFlow{

public string ep1='https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3MVG9d8..z.hDcPKBH.vazxgP2a3pz_hHw3pDYxj0JvosDjiE0opFXBmhsLdlFHyEZIWZ07FKfbvEivZvgCry&redirect_uri=https://c.ap8.visual.force.com/apex/WebServerFlow';

public string code{get;set;}
public void tokenizer(){
    Pagereference pg =null;
    if(code!=''){   
    String token = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'+'?grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=*******&client_id=3MVG9d8..z.hDcPKBH.vazxgP2a3pz_hHw3pDYxj0JvosDjiE0opFXBmhsLdlFHyEZIWZ07FKfbvEivZvgCry&redirect_uri=https://c.ap8.visual.force.com/apex/WebServerFlow&code='+code;    
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(token);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);   
    wrapper w = new wrapper();
    w = (wrapper)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),wrapper.class);

    string url = 'https://starhunter-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account123';   
    HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
    req2.setMethod('POST');
    req2.setEndpoint(w.instance_url);
    req2.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+w.access_token);
    req2.setBody('{"name":"Starhunte","phone":"1234567890","website":"http://aldfj@lsjfd.com"}');
    Http ht = new Http();
    HttpResponse resp2 = ht.send(req2);

   } 

}
public WebServerFlow(){
    code = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code');    
}
public pageReference callLogin(){
    Pagereference pg= new PageReference(ep1);
    return pg;
}

public class wrapper{
    public string access_token;
    public string signature;
    public string scope;
    public string id_token; 
    public string instance_url;
    public string id;
    public string token_type;
    public string issued_at;
}
}
```

The VF Page is:

```
<apex:page controller="WebServerFlow" >
 <apex:form >
     <apex:commandButton value="click to callout" action="{!callLogin}" />
     <apex:commandButton value="click to tokenize" action="{!tokenizer}" />           
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Following are the issues I am facing. I have tried to follow some of the existing posts but they are not working.

> I am able to receive the access token but not the refresh token.  But
>   on trying to use this access token to hit custom rest api , I am
>   getting the error : [{"message":"Session expired or
>   invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}] I checked the session
>   settings and the validity of access tokens is well within limits.
>
> I tried to change the Endpoint to the instance_url returned in the
>   response but it throws another error: LOGIN_OAUTH_INVALID_TOKEN
>
> The response does not return refresh token. I added
>   scope=refresh_token in the authorize step. But  that throws another
>   error:OAUTH_APPROVAL_ERROR_GENERIC : An unexpected error has occured
>   during authentication.

Comment: Is the code you get in step 1 vallid? as the code is sent to callback url

Comment: Yes the code is valid. Using the same code I am receiving access token